# exec() command with quotes not working

Tags: php, exec

My exec command looks like

```
exec("program.exe -x arg -o "something" $url");
```

Notice that here that something **MUST** be in double quotes or else the command won't work

I tried the following but all failed

```
exec("program.exe -x arg -o \"something\" $url");

exec('program.exe -x arg -o "something" $url');
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `escapeshellcmd`? That's what it's there for.

Comment: You know that variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, don't you? That's why the last one doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar now i feel stupid ....post the right command and i will accept your answer

Comment: I'm not sure why your second version, with the escaped quotes, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact i already had the correct answer

```
exec("program.exe -x arg -o \"something\" $url");
```

Works Perfect.

Most probably these alternatives work great as well

```
exec('program.exe -x arg -o' . '"something"' . $url);

OR

exec('program.exe -x arg -o "something" ' . $url);
```

Actually i have mistype the command and that's the reason why it was not working....

Answer (score 1):

```
exec('program.exe -x arg -o' . '"something"' . $url);

OR

exec('program.exe -x arg -o "something" ' . $url);
```